# Connect to Kafka HDInsight cluster via Azure webapp (Java)

Tags: java, azure, apache-kafka, azure-web-app-service, azure-hdinsight

I'm exploring Azure related technologies.

1. I have created Azure webapp using Java.
2. Created Kafka HDInsight cluster on Azure.

How to connect to Kafka cluster(*See point 2*) through Azure Java WebApp(*See point 1*) ?

One thing I did is took host-names from **Ambari-UI** to configure Kafka in my webapp, but it seems not working.

Also how to view logs/data in Kafka HDInsight cluster ?

Webapp Code for connection : "**10.0.0.13:9092**" address is taken from Ambari UI

```
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    String servers = "10.0.0.13:9092";
    properties.put("bootstrap.servers", servers);
    properties.put("key.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
    properties.put("value.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");

    kafkaProducer = new KafkaProducer(properties);
```

Comment: Please clarify "not working". Can you please show Code? Logs? Your webapp outputs log data somewhere, but it's not clear how you're running it

Comment: i've added code snippet for connection. But I didn't see any logs on webapp

Answer (score 0):

HDInsight does not allow direct connection to Kafka over the public internet > [HDInsight architecture planning.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/hdinsight/kafka/apache-kafka-connect-vpn-gateway#architecture-and-planning)
If you want to use Java Web App (in Tomcat), one of the possible solutions is to configure VNET integration (VPN) for WebApp and reconfigure Kafka to advertise IP of brokers instead of names, because DNS name resolution will not work over VPN > [Configure Kafka for IP advertising](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/hdinsight/kafka/apache-kafka-azure-functions#configure-kafka-for-ip-advertising).

P.S. For App Service Linux plan (Containers) currently VNET integration is not supported